# Refundable Flight Ticket in Malaysia Airlines?

Tags: tickets, refunds, malaysia-airlines

In Malaysia Airlines which plan (mhbasic/mhsmart/mhflex)  provides refundable ticket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact rules will actually vary slightly depending on the city pairs. On the Malaysia Airlines website, on the *Review Your Itinerary and Price* page there's a small link at the top for *View Fare Rules*. You can use that to check exactly what the rules would be for an given ticket you were thinking of buying

As a general rule though, mhbasic is the least flexible, then mhsmart, then mhflex.

Looking at a random mhbasic fare, I see things in the fare rules like:

- changes any time - charge gbp 100.00 for reissue/revalidation
- changes ticket reissue - rebooking / rerouting after ticketing- the above charge plus fare difference
- ticket is non-refundable in case of cancel/refund

So for that one, you can make changes to it for a £100 fee plus any extra fare costs at the time of the change, but you can't have any money back if you cancel.

.

Then looking at a random mhflex fare, I see things in the fare rules like:

- changes ticket reissue -  rebooking / rerouting after ticketing permitted with no fees plus fare difference
- cancellations permitted for cancel/refund. admin fee applies.
- after departure - cancellations permitted for cancel/refund. note - deduct the applicable one way fare in same or higher rbd and cancellation fee - if any- and refund the balance if any.

So, on that particular ticket, the mhflex ticket is refundable before departure for a small fee, and after departure less  the cost of a one-way for what you've already used (which may mean there's nothing to refund)

.

There is no universal answer, it'll depend on the city pairs, but mhflex is likely to be the one you need for full flexibility and near-refundable-ness. Check the fare rules for the full details / speak to a travel agent who can understand them and explain them to you!

Answer (score 3):

MH basic would be the cheapest of all the 3 fares. It is Non endorsable, non transferable and non refundable.Seats are limited and are subject to availability of the relevant booking class.  As it is the cheapest, this will be the bargain if you are absolutely sure about the dates you are flying as you are not allowed to change departure dates to/from destinations. If for some reason you are unable to travel on the date, the whole ticket is gone.  Nothing can be done about it.

MH Smart and MH Flex is having almost the same conditions except that Flex is the short for flexible which means that you can do a lot with the ticket You need to pay fees for changes to this type of ticket.  Its about the same with Smart except that I think MH Flex you can travel on code share airlines and pay a difference if the fare is higher.  Also you can choose your seats for free which for MH smart, you need to pay a fee.  MH Smart is the mid between the 2 fares, is also limited but has more options open if you want to change dates subject to the promotion period/type of aircraft depending on continents unlike MH flex which has no restriction. MH flex because of its flexibility is the more expensive of the 3.  The ticket is refundable subject to penalty fees.